# jQuery cloning divs from button click with incremental HTML data-id attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

I am using Twitter Bootstrap CSS framework + jQuery to build an UI.

In my interface, I have several divs and an external button that clones the last of them when clicked and inserts it in the DOM in the "new" last position, like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.addDiv', function() {
    var lastDiv = $(this).closest('.form-group').siblings().last();
    var id = lastDiv.data('id');
    var newDiv = lastDiv.clone(true);
    ...
```

Each div has a `data-id` HTML attribute with a number starting at 1, and I want the new dynamic divs to have subsequent ids. For that, I have:

```
    ...
    newDiv.attr('data-id', id + 1);
    newDiv.insertAfter(lastDiv);
});
```

Which does exactly what I want, but **ONLY** the first time the button is clicked... (i.e. `data-id` is correctly set to 2 only with divs already on page load, not dynamically added).
However, second an subsequent times the button is pressed (when a dynamic div is "the last"), `data-id` remains 2 although the newDivs keep inserting (the right way) one after the last...

Any idea of what could be happening?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `newDiv.attr('data-id',id+1)` with `newDiv.data( "id", id + 1 );`

What's happening is that you are attaching data-id to the DOM element as an attribute. JQuery does not register this as the element's data. Then, since you are cloning the div, each cloned div maintains a data-id of 2.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the point! You really have split hairs here :)